# ¿Como enviar los productos a comprar a api mercadopago?

Tags: nodejs, express

Desde **Angular** envio a **node/express** un **array** con los productos que el usuario va a comprar.

Desde **node/express** guardo la data que viene del **req.body** en un **array compra** de esta forma:

```js
let compra: [] = [];

compra = req.body; // guardo en el array la data del body

console.log(compra);
```

**Este es resultado por consola:**

```js
[
   'Borges Cuenta Buenos Aires',
   '1230.00',
   1,
  'Fuertes, Libres Y Nómadas', 
   '1290.00', 
 ]
```

Ahora, **mercadopago** utiliza esta estructura para almacenar los productos que se van a comprar:

```js
 // Crea un objeto de preferencia
      let preference = {
        items: [
          {    
            title: 'Mi producto',
            unit_price: 100,
            quantity: 1
          },
        ],
      };

      mercadopago.preferences
        .create(preference)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.body);
          // redirije a pagina de mercadopago
          res.redirect(response.body.init_point);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Entonces, la idea es guardar en este **objeto preference**, los productos que llegan en el **req.body**, intente hacer esto:

```js
let compra: [] = [];
  
  let items: [
    {
      title: "";
      unit_price: 0;
      quantity: 0;
    }
  ];
  
  compra = req.body;
  
  // paso la data del array compra al array items.
  for(let i = 0; i < compra.length; i++){
    items[i].title = compra[i];
    items[i].unit_price = compra[i];
    items[i].quantity = compra[i];
  }

 // console.log de los datos del array items
  for(let item of items){
    console.log('item: ' + item);
  }
```

Pero **node** muestra un error: **TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined:**.

Comment: ¿Puedes imprimir `items` y `compra` antes del `for`?  Parece ser que alguno de los dos está indefinido.

Comment: gracias por respoder, cuando intento imprimir items con console.log('items: ' + items); por consola devuelve: items: undefined. cuando en compra hago console.log(compra) si me imprime la data.

Comment: Tienes `let items: [ {...} ]`, cuando debería ser: `let items = [ {...} ]`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Yo pensé en eso, pero en ese caso ¿No debería de obtener un error de `unexpected token :`?

Comment: gracias por responder, corregi el let items =.............pero sale este error TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo los consejos una solucion para cargar los productos del **req.body** en el **objeto preference** fue:

1. Cree una interfaz en **node/express** **compramp**:

```js
export interface Compramp{
    title: string,
    unit_price: number,
    quantity: number 
}
```

En el la funcion **checkout** del **controlador.ts**

```js
// SDK de Mercado Pago
const mercadopago = require("mercadopago");
// importo la interfaz
import { Compramp } from '../compramp';
import { Request, Response } from "express";

mercadopago.configure({ 
  // acces token de produccion del vendedor
  access_token:
    "APP_USR-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx",
});

export const checkout = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
): Promise<Response> => {
 
  let compra = [{
    title: '',
    unit_price: 0,
    quantity: 0
  }]

  let items: Compramp[] = [];

  compra = req.body; // guardo la data del req.body en array compra

  // cargo la data del array compra en el array items
  for(let data of compra){
    items.push({
      title: data.title,
      unit_price: parseInt(data.unit_price.toString()),
      quantity: parseInt(data.quantity.toString())
    });
  }

  for(let p of items){
    console.log(p);
  }

  try {  
    // cargo la data de items en el objeto preference
    let preference = {
      items
    }
      mercadopago.preferences
      .create(preference)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.body);
        // redirije a pagina de mercadopago 
        res.redirect(response.body.init_point);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json("Internal server error");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema que tienes es que estás tratando de llenar `items[]` con los valores de compra tratando de acceder a los elementos según el largo de `compra`. El error que obtienes es porque deifnes `items` como un array de un solo elemento, pero `compra` es de más elementos y en el momento del `for` donde se hace la segunda iteración llegas a hacer algo cómo:

```
items[2].title = compra[2];
```

Lo cuál es un problema porque si existe `compra[2]`, pero no existe `items[2]`. Te sugiero que definas un array vacío como items y lo rellenes utilizando un método como `push`, algo cómo así:

```js
let items = [];

compra = req.body;

for (let i = 0; i < compra.length; i++) {
  //Asumo que las propiedades existen en compra[i] con el mismo nombre
  items.push({
    title: compra[i].title,
    unit_price: compra[i].unit_price,
    quantity: compra[i].quantity
  });
}
```

O mejor aún, utilizando `for ... of`:

```js
let items = [];

compra = req.body;

for (e of compra) {
  //Asumo que las propiedades existen en compra[i] con el mismo nombre
  items.push({
    title: e.title,
    unit_price: e.unit_price,
    quantity: e.quantity
  });
}
```

### UPDATE

Suponiendo que los datos llegan como un array que sigue una estructura definida de que cada 3 elementos representan una compra, entonces te propongo algo cómo:

```js
const CANTIDAD_PROPIEDADES = 3;

let items = [];

compra = req.body;

for (let i = 0; i < compra.length / CANTIDAD_PROPIEDADES; i++) {
  let base = i * CANTIDAD_PROPIEDADES;
  items.push({
    title: compra[base],
    unit_price: compra[base + 1],
    quantity: compra[base + 2]
  });
}
```

Te sugiero que cada elemento debería de estar encapsulado individualmente, esta estructura que se está usando no es adecuada y no saca provecho del lenguaje que estás usando. Es más complicada de leer, necesita de más código, es más propensa a errores, requiere de verificación adicional y no es escalable de una manera sencilla.

Un formato adecuado para `compra` sería algo como:

```
[
    {
      title: 'Borges Cuenta Buenos Aires';
      unit_price: '1230.00';
      quantity: 1;
    },
    {
      title: 'Fuertes, Libres Y Nómadas';
      unit_price: '1290.00';
      quantity: 1;
    },
 ]
```

Comment: gracias, lo que pasa es que sale error en esta lineas de codigo que escribiste:

Comment: items.title = compra.title;
  items.unit_price = compra.unity_price;
  items.quantity = compra.quantity;

Comment: Si no compartes los errores que obtienes es imposible ayudarte. No tenemos idea de cómo funciona tu implementación.

Comment: ademas, la compra puede estar compuesta por varios productos.

Comment: Si la compra puede estar compuesta por varios productos ¿Cómo explicarías el resultado que obtienes en tu primer ejemplo? Obtienes las propiedades de tu compra directamente, no un elemento de compra con varios elementos

Comment: Cuando en mi publicacion muestro cuando imprimo el array compra,  la consola muestra 2 productos diferentes(Borges Cuenta Buenos Aires,1230.00,1, Fuertes, Libres Y Nómadas, 1290.00, 1 ). No se si lo estoy interpretando bien. pero la idea es esos dos productos ponerlos en el array items de mercadopago.

Comment: Ahora entiendo que son dos compras, pero no entiendo porqué se imprimen así. Podrías por favor incluir en tu pregunta, un `console.log(compra)` con el resultado en consola, esto facilitaría la comprehensión

Comment: dale @FranAcuna gracias por la ayuda, ahi subi a la publicacion el resultado del console.log(compra)

Comment: Uh, entonces si es un array con los datos sueltos, parece una manera un poco descontrolada para manejar las compras, lo mejor sería que tuvieran algún tipo de encapsulamiento. En este caso, habría que suponer que el orden de una compra siempre tendrá tres elementos... Algo siguiendo un formato como `[title1,price1,quiantity1,title2,price2,quiantity2,etc]`. Voy a actualizar mi respuesta

Comment: gracias @FranAcuna me guié con tu UPDATE II  siguiendo el consejo de un formato adecuado para compra. Te parece que elimine de la publicacion tu UPDATE I ?

Comment: Me alegra que te sirve. ¿Quieres que elimine el update I?

Comment: si eliminalo, asi acepto la respuesta como valida.

Comment: Tienes razón, no aporta mucho a la respuesta. Eliminé el update I